# Почему изображения полупрозрачные?

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть ссылка с изображениями внутри

```
<a href="" class="HomeProjects__button_3icFk appear-animation HomeProjects__visible_3yRn4">
     смотреть все проекты
    <img src="/img/svg.b24bb05c.png" alt="" class="HomeProjects__svg_d_scl">
    <img src="/img/svg2.7498bd10.png" alt="" class="HomeProjects__svg2_NnFUO">
</a>
```

При ховере выходит так что первое изображение полупрозрачное и видно как нижнее двигается
https://take.ms/Ujaay
Что такое может быть и как с этим бороться?
Видео с примером https://take.ms/U924R.
Нет никаких opacity, пробовал svg еще, тоже самое. пробовал стилями, но не подошло.

Comment: А вы что сами не видите что у вас изображения разного качества и тональность (оттенок) белого на изображении со стрелкой отличается от другого изображения? просто если видите, то ответ очевиден, сделайте более равные изображения, точней перерисуйте стрелочку...

Comment: @RifmaMan они одинаковые, давайте представим что там svg, а работают так же! Svg одно и тоже просто удалены были лишние линии

Comment: Я имею в виду то, что из-за разницы толщины линий от стрелки и вашей горизонтальной палочки этот эффект и появляется, то изображение где стрелки по бокам у него толщина горизонтальной линии не совпадает с толщиной (размерами) изображения которое анимируется

Comment: @RifmaMan ну изображение одно и тоже, просто у второго стрелки затерты стеркой, соответственно толщина линии однаковая

Comment: Может после редактировании качество чуть чуть попортилось??? (сам я с svg не особо знаком), а попробуйте просто продублировать изображения со стрелочкой и подвигать его, будет ли этот эффект, если нет, то возьмите просто отредактируйте (ничего не делая) как будто вы затерли стрелки, сохраните и уже эту стрелку наложите

Comment: Ой, у вас png ведь файлы ) но там тоже можно с разным качеством сохранять так то...

Comment: @RifmaMan не, я использовал svg там тоже такое же. И другую svg которая из инета взята была.